# Build XML table using VB Datagridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

I have a web service that returns XML.

Here is an example of the code the is returned.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords">
    -<result>
        -<Accounts>
            -<row no="1">
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">1202xxx000000121001</FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">1202xxx000000071001</FL>
            -<FL val="Account Owner">
                <![CDATA[Fred Smith]]>
            </FL>
            -<FL val="Account Name">
                <![CDATA[The Oaks Dental Practice]]>
            </FL>
            -<FL val="Phone">
                <![CDATA[01202 123123]]>
            </FL>
                -<FL val="Account Number">
            <![CDATA[0]]>
            </FL>
            -<FL val="Account Type">
                <![CDATA[Prospect]]>
            </FL>
            -<FL val="Employees">
                 <![CDATA[0]]>
```

I am trying to pull this data into a datagridview using vb.net

The trouble is it only returns values based on the top level hierarchy, so I get a table with a column heading of "uri" and a value of "/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords"

If I use a more simple XML structure, for example http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml it works fine.

Here is my vb.net code:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Public Shared Sub DataSetSample1()

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim dsWeather As DataSet

        Try
            ' Create the web request  
            request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create( _
                   "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords?authtoken=????????3bb1c27c3116dc6b0275ea91&scope=crmapi"), HttpWebRequest)

            ' Get response  
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            ' Load data into a dataset  
            dsWeather = New DataSet()
            dsWeather.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream())

            ' Print dataset information  
            PrintDataSet(dsWeather)
        Finally
            If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
        End Try

        Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = dsWeather.Tables(0)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub PrintDataSet(ByVal ds As DataSet)

        ' Print out all tables and their columns  
        For Each table As DataTable In ds.Tables
            Console.WriteLine("TABLE '{0}'", table.TableName)
            Console.WriteLine("Total # of rows: {0}", table.Rows.Count)
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------")

            For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns
                Console.WriteLine("- {0} ({1})", column.ColumnName, column.DataType.ToString())
            Next  ' For Each column  

            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine)
        Next  ' For Each table    ' Print out table relations  
        For Each relation As DataRelation In ds.Relations
            Console.WriteLine("RELATION: {0}", relation.RelationName)
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------")
            Console.WriteLine("Parent: {0}", relation.ParentTable.TableName)
            Console.WriteLine("Child: {0}", relation.ChildTable.TableName)
            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine)
        Next  ' For Each relation  

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        DataSetSample1()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I am looking for some help on how to pull back the correct values to build the table.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim input As String = _
            "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" + _
            "<response uri=""/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords"">" + _
                "<result>" + _
                    "<Accounts>" + _
                        "<row no=""1"">" + _
                            "<FL val=""ACCOUNTID"">1202xxx000000121001</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""SMOWNERID"">1202xxx000000071001</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""Account Owner"">" + _
                                "<![CDATA[Fred Smith]]>" + _
                            "</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""Account Name"">" + _
                                "<![CDATA[The Oaks Dental Practice]]>" + _
                            "</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""Phone"">" + _
                                "<![CDATA[01202 123123]]>" + _
                            "</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""Account Number"">" + _
                                "<![CDATA[0]]>" + _
                            "</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""Account Type"">" + _
                                "<![CDATA[Prospect]]>" + _
                            "</FL>" + _
                            "<FL val=""Employees"">" + _
                                "<![CDATA[0]]>" + _
                            "</FL>" + _
                        "</row>" + _
                    "</Accounts>" + _
                "</result>" + _
            "</response>"
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(input)
        Dim rows As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants("row").ToList()

        Dim rowCount = 1
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        For Each row In rows
            If rowCount = 1 Then
                For Each col As XElement In row.Elements("FL")
                    Dim colName As String = col.Attribute("val").Value
                    dt.Columns.Add(colName, GetType(String))
                Next col
            End If
            rowCount += 1
            Dim rowData As New List(Of String)
            For Each col As XElement In row.Elements("FL")
                rowData.Add(col.Value)
            Next col
            dt.Rows.Add(rowData.ToArray())
        Next row

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
End Class
​
```

Comment: Thanks, but my original code pulled the XML via a Web Service. The code you have provided seems to have a static input "Dim input As String =". Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes.  Putting the XML directly into a data set ends up with the data going down the rows instead across in the columns.  You need to put the XML into an XDocument then parse the document.  Once you get the XML you need to put the XML into a document using XDocument.Parse(XML string).